# Routing View Sub Folders to controller in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-routing

Zend newbie here.

I have an admin folder in my View linked to an admin controller, but I need a sub folder(s) within the admin view to handle various functions.

For example: views/scripts/admin and I also want views/scripts/admin/linksfunction or views/scripts/admin/adduserfunction.

My question is, how do I hook these subdirectories with my controllers? I'm looking to handle the functions either within the AdminController or even separate controllers. Does anybody know how I would accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods for accomplishing this.

If you have an action for each functionality (adduserfunction & linksfunction),  you can use `viewAction helper`  [Action View Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.action)
From `views/scripts/admin.index.phtml` call `echo $this->action('adduserfunction', 'admin')` and `echo $this->action( 'linksfunction', 'admin')`. This will render the whole action to the view. It is very straightforward and handy. But view action helpers are considered to be very expensive. Check this ZF Manual [performance.view.action](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/performance.view.html#performance.view.action)

Another method is to use [Actionstack](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.actionstack) where you can add more than one action to a stack and execute it sequentially.

Another method is to use either [Partial Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial) or [Zend_View's render()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.scripts.html). Use partial() only when really necessary, because it is very expensive.

These are few sources that will help you
[When to use viewscripts/partials vs view helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389531/zend-framework-when-to-use-viewscripts-partials-vs-view-helpers)
[Why the Zend Framework Actionstack is Evil](http://www.rmauger.co.uk/2009/03/why-the-zend-framework-actionstack-is-evil/)